# Android Development- Change gridview images continously after 2 sec- How can I use handler to achieve this task?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a question regarding grid views in android.
I have a grid of 5x5 images. And I want to change these images continously. Loads new set of images from the array every time.
I have a random generator function which changes the value of the mThumbIds array after it loads every time.
But I am unable to apply the new images before it needs some event to render the new set of images. Here I do not have any event. I want them to change continuously.
Can you please me.
Unable to find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an AsyncTask to change your images ? The AsyncTask could change one image, then launch a new AsyncTask.

An other option is to use a Handler. That may be your best option actually. http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentthreading-part-1-handlers/

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the response.. But I tried the handler. It doesnt seem to work. I have 5x5 images in my grid. Now after 2 seconds, I have a function called ShuffleArray() which I call and that shuffles my mThumbIds array of my image adapter. And then I call notifydatasetchanged to show the updated grid. This is what I want to do. The handler solution didnt work. I have tried it before. :( I want that array of 25 images to change after I have shuffled it after a few seconds. So tis makes it look like some continuous motion. Could you tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: Also can you tell me how I should use the handler.... ? Maybe I am doing something wrong there..

Comment: Show how you use it. Update your question. The approach of @rgocha is the right one.

Comment: Thank you @Snicolas. I updated the Q now. So how do I define the handler for this. My handler shoud do this... imageAdpater.shuffleArray(); imageAdapter.notifydatasetchanged().... so do i need the sendmessage function.. this is the first android coe i am working on. So I am sorry if i am asking too many Q...

Comment: I need only those two lines of code to be repeated a certain number of times. So can i put this in the void run() ?? or do i need the handleMessage() ??

Comment: Look at the tutorial I gave you. You must override handleMessage and, there, put the code that will get triggered every X seconds. Then you need some to send a message. In you handleMessage method, make a counter. If the counter is below a threadshold, then resend a message. That's quite easy, but please don't copy paste things, understand handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a timer to trigger the image changing function every 2 seconds?. If so try a Handler. Something like

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // init grid and set first batch of images
    }

    protected void onResume() {
         mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateImagesTask , 2000);
     }


    private Runnable mUpdateImagesTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
               // Code to change the images

               // call me in 2 seconds...
               mHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000); // 2 seconds
            }
     };
```

If you want to stop the loop just put some conditions to call Handler.postDelayer() inside mUpdateImagesTask or call mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImagesTask) from outside the Runnable (at a button click, i.e).

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the response.. But I tried the handler. It doesnt seem to work. I have 5x5 images in my grid. Now after 2 seconds, I have a function called ShuffleArray() which I call and that shuffles my mThumbIds array of my image adapter. And then I call notifydatasetchanged to show the updated grid. This is what I want to do. The handler solution didnt work. I have tried it before. :( I want that array of 25 images to change after I have shuffled it after a few seconds. So tis makes it look like some continuous motion. Could you tell me where I am going wrong.